# Fedora21 Cloud Base refuses to enable eth1 on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, cloud-init, fedora-21

Fedora21 Cloud comes in 2 flavors. Base and Atomic. I'm trying to install the BASE version using VirtualBox. The Atomic version will enable dhcp on eth1 if it's enabled, however, BASE refuses to enable eth1. I installed nmcli and tried any number of options and I have not been able to get things going correctly. I'm thinking that if nmcli is not the way to go then there must be something in cloud-init which would be a preferred method.

How do I activate DHCP on eth1?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora, like most RHEL derivatives, stores network configuration in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`.  If you want `eth1` to pull an address with dhcp, create `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` with the following content:

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

And then run `ifup eth1`.  You can perform these changes as part of a `user-data` script if you are using `cloud-init`.